# Can't force download - PHP curl

Tags: php, curl, fopen

We're exporting some data as csv, and triggering that with a jQuery ajax form submission. I can get the basics of it working, what I can't seem to get is forcing download the file after its written.
PHP

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['payerEmail'];
echo $_SESSION['password']; 
$url = 'http://www.ninjatrader-support2.com/sugar/FXCMLicense.php';
$FXCMAction = $_REQUEST["FXCMAction"];
$payerEmail = $_SESSION['payerEmail'];
$password = $_SESSION['password'];
$fields = array(
'FXCMAction'=>urlencode($FXCMAction),
'payerEmail'=>urldecode($payerEmail),
'password'=>urldecode($password)
);
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
$fields_string = rtrim($fields_string,'& ');

$ch = curl_init($url);
session_write_close();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$directory='/home/ninja002/public_html/FXCMReports/';
$filename = 'XCMLicense.csv';
$handle = fopen($directory.$filename, 'w');
fwrite($handle, $output);
echo $output;
curl_close($ch);

?>
```

As always, any advice is much appreciated. TY.

Comment: What's the error message? How did you determine if you've got write permission for that file or directory?

Comment: Did you check `directory/` folder have write permission? Could be PHP may not have write permission to write a file.

Comment: I added permission "0777" in fireFTP > Properties

Comment: my best for debugging this would be to see what's inside `curl_getinfo()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php

Comment: what am I looking for with dumping curl info?

Comment: Pat of my issue was the path to the directory, I had to do it like "/home/user/public_html/Directory/"

Answer (score 0):

Hope this can save someone the headache it gave me. Here's how to do it (at least in my case):

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $url = 'http://www.remotesite/script.php';
    $Foo = $_REQUEST["Foo"];
    $Bar = $_SESSION['Bar'];
    $password = $_SESSION['password'];
    $fields = array(
        'Foo'=>urlencode($Foo),
        'Bar'=>urldecode($Bar),
        'password'=>urldecode($password)
    );
    foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
    $fields_string = rtrim($fields_string,'& ');
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    session_write_close();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $directory='/home/usr/public_html/Directory/';
    $filename = 'AwesomeData.csv';
    $handle = fopen($directory.$filename, 'w');
    fwrite($handle, $output);
    header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="AwesomeData.csv"');
    echo $output;
?>
```